# How do we get the absolute path to the applications root directory using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have an app that may run at http://serverA/m/ or http://serverA/mobile/. I have a shared  header with a search form that needs to go to http://serverA/*installationName*/search.

However, if I use `<form action="/search">` it goes to the root of the server, not the tomcat application.

If I use `<form action="search">` it goes to a path relative to the current page. (i.e http://serverA/m/someOtherPage/search

I've tried `<c:url value="search">` and `<c:url value="/search">` but neither of them seem to work.

In intelliJ, `<c:url value="/search">` gives me "Cannot resolve controller URL /search" even though I have a controller defined with @RequestMapping("/search")

Comment: How did you prepare your search URL? Did you write it directly in the href attribute by hand? What is your href? Do you use any taglibs? Do you use spring-mvc with jsp or any other view frameworks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<form action="<c:url value="/search" />" />
```

Using `<c:url>` is the way. Ignore what the IDE tells you. They are not good at that. Just try to run it.

Comment: Sorry, apparently I didn't denote the thmnl so ittried to render :/ my bad.

Comment: This still does not work, I'm gonna combine it with dwbs answe and see what I come up with

Comment: I believe part of the problem is the IntelliJ Idea is starting my app up at /, but it still resides at /m/, thus the application context is /. while the app really runs at /m/

And I have no idea why this is occuring.

Comment: Well, a full url is localhost:8080/m/

Comment: which means the context path is `/m`. Which in turn means your links will have `/m` prepended whenever you use `<c:url>`

Comment: but for some strange reason it isn't. I'm beginning to think this is less programatic an dmore with how IntelliJ is launching my tomcat instance.

Comment: Configure your context path (on the Deployment tab) for Tomcat in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 4):

Bozho is right. I have used HTML BASE tag too:

```
<base href="${pageContext.request.scheme}://${pageContext.request.serverName}:${pageContext.request.serverPort}${pageContext.request.contextPath}/" />
```

If you can put this tag in a few places (ideally in only one JSP) you can get your code cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can (apart from other responders hints) also use Spring JSP tag (spring:url) which is modeled after the JSTL c:url tag (see Bozhos reply). The tld reference:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.url

And the bottom of this mvc:resources block for an example use:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

you will not be able to imbed the c:url tag directly in the attribute, if your form tag is a jsp tag (perhaps, <sf:form>).

In that situation I do the following:

```
<c:url var="someName" value="some uri value"/>
<sf:form path="${someName}" ...>
```